# How to disable zone.js in a standalone angular apllication?

Tags: angular, zone.js

when launching angular with a standalone component like

```
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent,{...
```

how can we set the ngZone parameter

With modules it goes like:

```
platformBrowserDynamic()                   
  .bootstrapModule(AppModule, { ngZone: 'noop' })
```

but I did not see a way to do the same with bootstrapApplication()

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there's no option for it at the moment (v15)

> This was a deliberate choice we made when designing
> bootstrapApplication - we chose to create a minimal API that didn't
> carry over any of the options from the bootstrapModule API.
>
> ngZone: 'noop' is what I would consider an advanced, low-level option.
> It's not something you can just set - using this option requires
> completely rethinking how state works in your application and how
> change detection is triggered.
>
> For now, continue to use bootstrapModule if you require a zoneless
> application. Reactivity, Change Detection, and "zoneless" is an area
> of focus for us in 2023, so we hope to have a real story here at some
> point.

More details and workaround could be found here: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/47538